# Web service timeout error

Tags: sql, reporting-services, timeout

We are running SQL Server 8. Every day when our users try to run a report for the first time it takes too long and eventually displays the error message below (other subsequent runs for the report work fine). Here is the error message.

Server Error in '/' Application.
The operation has timed out
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out

Can anyone help with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide some other logs of the error, what you are reporting is a timeout error, but not the "root cause" of the timeout. If I had to guess, and I rather not, but here goes, the SQL takes a while for the first report as there is, a lot of new logins (early in the morning you said?) no data stored in the cache (SQL caches data when it is first used)

Comment: That is user-end message we need the server-end message

Comment: Where can i find the server-end message?

Comment: Are you restarting your DB over-night or SSRS, or the whole server?

Comment: When you say *SQL Server 8* - do you mean SQL Server **2000** (which has v8), or do you mean SQL Server **2008** ??

Comment: Sorry i meant SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only slow on the first run, you can fix it by running a "warm-up" script.  This can be as simple as setting a timer to call a web address (a report in your SSRS).  The Windows Task Scheduler is pretty easy for this purpose.  I've seen people do it for web servers, DBs, reports, nearly anything that is slow on the first run (due to caching or just-in-time compliling).